# Iterate over page data stored in a settings Orderable

Tags: django, wagtail

I have created a Wagtail settings page that allows me to select 1-5 pages which I'd like to display in my site footer as 'Most popular pages'. I've done this using an Orderable and PageChooserPanel, see below:

```
@register_setting
class MostPopularPosts(BaseSetting, ClusterableModel):
    display_most_popular_posts_in_sidebar = models.BooleanField("Display most popular posts in sidebar", default=True, help_text='Untick to hide the most popular posts widget')
    panels = [
        FieldPanel('display_most_popular_posts_in_sidebar'),
        InlinePanel('popular_pages', max_num=5, min_num=1, label="Most popular pages"),
    ]

class MostPopularPostPages(Orderable):
    settings_page = ParentalKey(MostPopularPosts, related_name="popular_pages")    
    popular_page = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailcore.Page',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+',
        verbose_name="Page Link"
    )
    panels = [
        PageChooserPanel('popular_page')
    ]
```

The above works fine, but I'm struggling to get the content of the individual pages selected to appear in my templates.

```
{% for popular_page in settings.home.MostPopularPosts.popular_pages.all %}              
  <li>
    {{ popular_page.title }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

The above loop iterates the expected number of times, but {{ popular_page.title }} doesn't output the page titles. I've tried {{ popular_page.specific.title }} but this also doesn't work.

If someone could explain how I should be structuring my template tags to access the individual pages data within my for loop here I'd be eternally grateful.

Comment: Does that query return the expected results when executed in the Django shell? I don't know your project but would have expected the query to be something more direct like `settings.popular_pages.all`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loop will return instances of the `MostPopularPostPages` model, which are not page objects in their own right. To get a page object (and thus access the `title` field), you'll need to follow the ForeignKey that points to `wagtailcore.Page`, which is the `popular_page` relation. Renaming your existing `popular_page` variable to `item` to avoid confusion, we get:

```
{% for item in settings.home.MostPopularPosts.popular_pages.all %}
  <li>
    {{ item.popular_page.title }}
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks for helping, I really appreciate it (twice in one day as well!)